# How to add a a Apps domain account as a alpha tester?

Tags: google-play

According to https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en , You should be able to add @gmail.com accounts and Google Apps accounts as Alpha testers.

I've now tested this and only @gmail.com accounts works, and not Apps accounts.

Is this a bug or am i missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I blame this one on cosmic radiation, because when trying to screenshot the error for a support ticket, everything worked as expected.